# Sybase update only the last record that fulfill conditions

Tags: sql, sql-update, sql-order-by, inner-join, sybase

I´m trying to update a record that fulfills some conditions but I need it to be the **last one**, I've read that I should use an order by and a limit. (I don't want to use a subquery to first fetch the last reccord that fulfill conditions ... I feel aint cool, should be a better way ...)

I've tried:

```
UPDATE table_1
SET some_field= 'value'
FROM table_1 t1 
INNER JOIN table_2 t2 ON t1.field_1 = t2.field_1
WHERE t1.some_field = 'some_value' and t1.seome_other_field = 'some_other_value'
ORDER BY t1.some_field DESC limit 1
```

**But I get Error (156) incorrect syntax near keyword 'ORDER'**

For what I can see in Sybase docs I'm using the keywords in the correct order ... 
http://infocenter.sybase.com/archive/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc38151.1260/html/iqref/Update.htm

**Am I breaking some rule ?**

I´m sure is something pretty obvious ... but right now can't see it  ...

Sybase 15.7.0.501.1011

Comment: Are you using Sybase IQ? That's the documentation you linked to. It would be helpful if you specify which Sybase DB product and version you are using.

Comment: Sorry I'm not using Sybase IQ, is Sybase 15.7.0.501.1011
I'm still getting the same error. Are there any rules or conditions in the inner join that I might be breaking?, therefore not being able to use 'ORDER BY'

Comment: You could maybe try the Sybase syntax for the join, instead of ANSI?  I'll update my answer accordingly.

Comment: I've tried and I get the same error ... I think it might be some special conditions of the tables ... 'cos that seems to me a very valid query ...

Comment: I do not think we can have `order by` clause in update query. if you want to only update last row than create a `clustered index` (DESC), set the rowcount 1, run your update query (after removing `order by`) and than drop the index.

Comment: Ah that makes sense.  I think to use the order by you have to use a sub-query.

Answer (score 0):

With out using a subquery, or changing your query you could use `set rowcount` to limit the number of updates:

```
set rowcount 1
go
UPDATE table_1
SET some_field= 'value'
FROM table_1 t1, table_2 t2 
WHERE t1.field_1 = t2.field_1
AND t1.some_field = 'some_value' and t1.seome_other_field = 'some_other_value'
ORDER BY t1.some_field DESC
go
set rowcount 0
go
```

This is a session level setting, and `0` is the default value to return all rows affected.

Comment: It's looking like a subquery is your best bet..I'll delete my answer tomorrow.